# blur event and javascript/html

Tags: javascript, listener, dom-events, blur

I have to ask for a user's name and id number. Using event handlers such for blur or submit events and check that the user text box isn't empty and the id is a number and I have to put up an alert box if false.

Here is my html:.

```
<form id = "form" action = "">
     <p>
         <label class = "classname" for = "name">Username:</label>
         <input type = "text" id = "name" placeholder = "enter your Username">
     </p>
     <p>
         <label class = "classname" for = "idnum">ID Number:</label>
         <input type = "text" id ="idnumber" placeholder = "enter id number">
     </p>
</form>
```

and here is my Javascript code:

```
var helpArray = ["your doing it wrong", "your wrong"]
var helpText;

function init(){
     helpText = document.getElementById("helpText");
     registerListeners(document.getElementById("name"),0);
     registerListeners(document.getElementById("idnumber"),0);
}

function registerListeners(object, messageNumber){
     object.addEventListener( "blur",function(){
          helpText.innerHTML = helpArray [0];
     }, false);

     object.addEventListener( "focus",function(){
          helpText.innerHTML = helpArray [messageNumber];
     }, false);
}
window.addEventListener("load",init,false);
```

as you can see I have been just trying to go by my textbook, haven't made much progress.

Comment: The code you have so far sets the `helpText` content to the same message on `focus` _and_ `blur` of either element, so it never seems to change. You probably should set it to an empty string on `blur`, also your `helpArray` has two messages - did you intend them to apply one per field? Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FGE6p/ (As an aside, I assume your final code will have friendly and descriptive error messages?)

Comment: how do i make it so that it checks for the 2 situations though?  and yea, the final code will have better error messages.

Comment: there is no  `html tag` with `id=helpText`...

Comment: @Alex I read your question, but don't understand what you want to do... however, I think I know the solution of your problem... post your target (that you want to do) as comment...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling functions too many times you can use simple code like the one below.Calling functions in javascript many times may result in performance costs

```
window.onload = init;

    function init(){
        helpText = document.getElementById("helpText");
        document.getElementById("name").onblur =  function() {
          helpText.innerHTML = helpArray [0];}, false);
       }
       document.getElementById("idnumber").onblur =  function() {
          helpText.innerHTML = helpArray [0];}, false);
       }
     }
```

you can assign functions to any events like above example, you may also use onfocus,onkeyUp..etc..